# inserting a field the a_i value of another field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following fields: `gallery(picID, picTimeStamp, location)`.

What I want is that when someone is uploading a new picture to the gallery, the location will get the same value that `picID` gets (and `picID` gets its value by auto increment).

I have tried:

```
"INSERT INTO gallery(picID, picTimeStamp, location) VALUES (null,'.time().',picID)"
```

but it is not working. I do not get any errors, the location just always has a zero in it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you completely ignore the concept of normalization and store the same autoincrement ID in two different columns of the same table? Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: because "location" field will be changed if i want to bring the photo up or down in the gallery showing order. by default i want it to be the same as picID. but when the superuser will click "up" button it will increase the "location" field and decrease the one that was above it. I hope you understand what I ment... Thanx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON gallery FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   DECLARE next_id INT; 
   SET next_id = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM gallery WHERE TABLE_NAME='gallery'); 
   SET NEW.location=next_id; 
END
```

edit: Should be after insert trigger instead of before because auto_increment number only gets set after the record is inserted. Sorry bout that!

Comment: is this code supposed to be written to the mySQL Server's console? or I don't understand (obviously it isn't php code...)

Comment: a trigger is a database object that is stored in the database like a table, view, stored routine... and gets called from your php code. The above code is the syntax to create such a trigger and yes - it is written to the mysqlserver console.

Comment: I'm using a shared host =\ so the only way I can get to the database is through PhpMyAdmin. So, unfortunately I guess I cannot use this :(

Comment: I thought it might have an easier way. Thanks for trying help!

Comment: How do you create tables in the database. Create a trigger the same way.

Answer (score -1):

Your table should be like this:

```
id               |  int        |  primary key/autoincrement
order            |  int        |  index
picTimeStamp     |  timestamp
```

and then if you want to create a new entry below pass the order number by GET:

```
function createBelow(){
if(isset($_GET["orders"])){  
    $orders = $_GET["orders"];
    $query = "UPDATE links SET orders=orders+1 WHERE orders>$orders ORDER BY     orders DESC"; 
    mysql_query($query);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `mydb`.`mytable` (`orders`) VALUES ($orders+1);";
    mysql_query($query);
}

}
```

The default value takes care of id and timestamp, you don't enter these.

Comment: NEVER show anyone code like this, especially when you teaching someone. You ignore elementary security rules (your code is "ready" for SQL Injection) and logic rules `mysql_query()` may always fail - you do not even bother to check. Even you want to tell it's pseudocode, it is bad pseudocode. Not to mention mysql_* is obsolete and shall not be used (use mysqli_* or PDO)

Comment: Ignore the above comment, I've used something similar, and it's sufficient to work for something like what you're trying to do.  Technology changes, so what? Are you going to stop driving a '76 camaro because the manufacturer doesn't make parts for it anymore?

Comment: Bad habits do not become good habits just because you been doing the former previously

Comment: Thanks for trying help me. I do use PDO for my project and I won't enter that code because it is risky. no offense...